# Validate date and datetime with Bootstrap datetime picker, Jquery validation plugin in an Asp.Net MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am currently developping a MVC Asp.Net 4.6 WebApp with [Bootstrap 3.1.1](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/), [Eonasdan datetime picker v4.7.14](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and [jquery validation plugin v1.14.0](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

And I've got some problem validating the date.

- My Model looks like that:

  ```
  public class PersonModel{
      ...

      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
      public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

      ...        
  }
  ```
- My View looks like that:

  ```
  <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DateOfBirth):
      <span class="text-danger"><b>*</b></span>
      <div class="input-group datepicker">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth, new {@class = "form-control", @data_date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY", @placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY"})
      </div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
  ```
- The associated Js code to init th datetime picker:

  ```
  (function () {
      // Init bootstrap date/time pickers
      $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
          useCurrent: false
      });
  })(jQuery);
  ```

  Using `jQuery.validator`, even if the the date looks good, I always get this error:

  [image]

  I know that `jQuery.validator` works fine with the jquery.ui.datepicker but how can I make it work with the bootstrap.datetimepicker ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can overrides the `date` method of the `Jquery.validator` plugin :

```
(function () {
    // overrides the jquery date validator method
    jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        // All dates are valid....
        return true;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Because the [bootstrap datetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), you can check if the date is valid like that:

```
(function () {
    // overrides the jquery date validator method
    jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        // We want to validate date and datetime
        var formats = ["DD/MM/YYYY", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"];
        // Validate the date and return
        return moment(value, formats, true).isValid();
    };
})(jQuery, moment);
```

Comment: What if I want to use both validate date and datetime on the same form. You are overriding "date" method.

Comment: @Kai sorry can't really remember, this is an old post from 3years old ... but from the second code snippet I can see that one of the valid format is a datetime so should be able to validate bothe date and datetime,  have you tried ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the code clearly, it really works well. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @Kai, no worries. You can also add others format if you need. this was working for me but you may want to adjust formats based on your use case